# The more ... the more statement

Tags: comparative-constructions

I want to write the following sentence using *the more ... the fewer* statement.

> There are 50 soldiers and 5 missions to be carried out.
>
> If N soldiers are assigned to the missions, then 50-N soldiers support the soldiers assigned to the missions in the rear.

My first question is: **do I need the word *is* or *are* written out twice in these statements**?

My second question is: **do I need the definite article before the word *number***?

My third question is: **do I need to use the word *number* at all**?

That is,

> - the more the number of the soldiers assigned to the missions **is**, the fewer the number of the soldiers that can play a role as assistants in the rear **is**.
> - the more the number of the soldiers assigned to the missions, the fewer the number of the soldiers that can play a role as assistants in the rear.

---

> - **the more number** of the soldiers assigned to the missions **is**, the fewer number of the soldiers that can play a role as assistants in the rear **is**.
> - **the more number** of the soldiers assigned to the missions, the fewer number of the soldiers that can play a role as assistants in the rear.

---

> - the more **the** soldiers assigned to the missions **are**, the fewer the soldiers that can play a role as assistants in the rear **are**.
> - **the more soldiers** assigned to the missions, the fewer solders that can play a role as assistants in the rear.

Which one is the best? If there is other better sentences, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a sentence like this one, I'd try to keep the wording concise. The more verbose the sentence, the harder it is to follow.

I think what you are trying to say would be better expressed using *as*, because you are analyzing the relationship between (N) and (50–N):

> *As more soldiers are assigned to the forward mission, fewer soldiers are available to assist in the rear*.

Comment: Thank you, I will use what you recommend. (Just wondering, are the sentences listed above grammatically wrong, or uncomfortable to see? If they are acceptable, which is the best?)

Comment: I wouldn't call your originals "grammatically wrong," but I would say they are overly wordy and that makes them awkward and difficult to follow.